# cannot release C++ game project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, sfml

I created a project and did some changes to that project in order to get access to SFML. (I'm following a tutorial, that's what they did). After that I exported it as a template.
Then I created a new project from this template and code the game. I used SFML library for that. It all works fine in debug mode. But when I select the release option, all the classes I have used from SFML are shown as undefined. Game works fine on debug mode.

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtRQw.png)

Comment: Chances are you made some changes to the project to tell it where include directories were and what libraries to link. You probably only made those changes to the debug target. Apply them to release as well.

Comment: thank you @RetiredNinja. that was the problem. all the settings i did for debug selected. now i changed those settings with release mode. all good now. thank you..